# confusion regarding the notation $Z_n$ in group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Some places I see $\mathbb{Z_n}$ defined as a group wrt to integer mod n. For Example : [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-spring-2015/structures/tp6-1/vertical-96037fd2d933/modular-exponentiation-the-ring/) and in other places $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is used to define ring of residue classes modulo n.

And which one of these represent Z/nZ?

Comment: What conflict do you see in those definitions?  (Note: I figure you wrote $m$ when you meant to write $n$)

Comment: All rings are abelian groups with respect to addition. It's part of the definition.

Comment: The notation is unfortunately ambiguous. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is both a group and a ring, and since $n\mathbb{Z}$ is both a normal subgroup and an ideal, you can construct the abelian group quotient $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, and the ring quotient $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Which one you are talking about (the group or the ring) usually is given via context, or an explicit statement. The notation $\mathbb{Z}_n$ or $\mathbf{Z}_n$ is common among group theorists, but many ring theorist have told me they object to it being used for the group (the notation $C_n$,  "cyclic of order $n$", is preferable)

Comment: $\mathbb Z_n$ and $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ are the "same" in all respects; the difference is a matter of construction. As groups, rings, and in the case $p$ is prime, domains/fields.

Comment: To make things even more confusing, when $n$ is a prime you also have a completely different ring, the $p$-adic integers, which are denote $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Number theorists thus prefer $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for the ring, and $C_n$ for the group.

Comment: But in the end, the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is "built on top" of the group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ in the same way that the ring $(\mathbb{Z},+,\times)$ is "built on top" of the group $(\mathbb{Z},+)$.

Answer (score 6):

There is only one cyclic group of order $n$ up to isomorphism. It is either written multiplicatively as $$C_n=\{e,a,a^2,\ldots a^{n-1}\},$$ or additively as
$$\Bbb Z/n \quad \text{ or } \quad \Bbb Z/(n) \quad \text{ or }\quad \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z \quad \text{ or }\quad \Bbb Z_n.$$ So we have at least five different notations for this group.

The notation $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ denotes the quotient group of the group $\Bbb Z$ by the normal subgroup $n\Bbb Z$. The notation $\Bbb Z_p$, for $n=p$ prime is ambiguous, because of the $p$-adic integers, as Arturo already mentioned. Actually, the notation $\Bbb Z/(n)$ also denotes the ring, where $I=(n)=n\Bbb Z$ is a principal ideal in the ring $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more dupe answers to FAQs.